# Zabbix graph monitoring

Tags: zabbix

I am new in Zabbix, I tried to understand in the Zabbix manual on how to create a graph but it is not clear for me.

I need to know the steps for monitoring any device, such as router, by representing on a graph.

What is the elements necessary before creating a graph for monitoring a device ?
How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In Zabbix you can graph any item's value.

An [item](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items) is a specific object of a monitored host: from cpu usage to the number of RDP sessions or an snmp value as "Interface WAN Input bytes" etc.

In order to collect items you need to configure a host (your target device) and link it to a template (blueprint of what you need to monitor): most base templates are already configured with graphs or graphs prototypes.

If you want to monitor a router or a similar network device you will need:

- a read snmp community configured on the device
- the SNMP base provided by Zabbix 3.4

Regarding "how to do that": [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/quickstart) you can find a quickstart guide, from logon to template creation